# Print error with custom script with nameERROR

Tags: python

I am trying to get the variable to define but it keeps saying stuff about the print (writetext) part.

This is for a small project I'm working on called adder (cause it's weaker)

How do I fix this?

```
#making an alternate ****** method of coding in python
#ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
#contact me on github to get permission to post a modification
def writetext(str):
    print(str)

def changetext(str):
    str = str
    
def textread(str):
    input(str)

def addfunctions(str):
    import pygame

writetext("test")
var = textread("works?")

changetext(a == "b")
writetext(a)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: test
works?sda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Terrible python addon.py", line 19, in <module>
    changetext(a == "b")
NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Ive given all that is there. I didnt do any formatting for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the functions incorrectly. Try adding `return` at the end of your `textread()` function, for example, it should look more like this:

```py
def textread():
     user_input = input()
     return user_input

text = textread()

print(text) -> will print the user input
```

You also have incorrect syntax throughout the code:

- First, the variable `a` is not defined (i.e. what is it equivalent to e.g. `a = ???`).
- Second, in `(a == 'b')` you are asking if variable `a` is the same as the string 'b', so inside the brackets you receive `True` or `False`.

Then you call the function with the statement False in it like this: `changetext(False)`.

Comment: Thankyou. This works. 

I am programming this at midnight so probably a lack of sleep sympton lol